# get new object from object in java script

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object

I have an object that contains so many items but I want export  just value of the name and family as new object by name newObj this is my object and code I try but it doesn't work

```js
const Symbol = {
  city: 'canada',
  work: 'developer',
  id: 13276298846607,
  postId: '22222',
  cs: '53',
  name: 'sam',
  family:'wbb',
  adress :'candan canada',
  cfield: 12566,
  }
   const myfunction = () => {
    const myData = [];
      const obj = {};
      obj.price = symbol['family'];
      obj.vol = symbol['name'];
      myData?.push(obj);
    return {
      data: myData,
    };
  };
   this is my exept return =>
   {name:'sam', family:'wbb'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the needed props and assign them to your required variable.

You can read object restructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const Symbol = {
  city: "canada",
  work: "developer",
  id: 13276298846607,
  postId: "22222",
  cs: "53",
  name: "sam",
  family: "wbb",
  adress: "candan canada",
  cfield: 12566,
};

const {
  name,
  family
} = Symbol
const newObj = {
  name,
  family
}
console.log("newObj", newObj)
```